# Dr racket Reunite 2 list

Tags: function, scheme, racket

I'm having trouble dealing with an error in Dr Racket:a function that reunite 2 lists

```
(define (reunite L1 L2)
(foldr (Î»(e init) 
(if (member e init) init (cons e init))) 
  null 
(append L1 L2)
))
```

The error is:
     **init: illegal (unparenthesized) use of class keyword in: init**

And what does **Î»** means?
If I eliminate it it throws the same error.Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you were aiming for:

```
(define (reunite L1 L2)
  (foldr (lambda (e init)
           (if (member e init)
               init
               (cons e init)))
         null
         (append L1 L2)))
```

The `Î»` character is a `λ`, to avoid encoding problems it's safer to just write `lambda` instead. As a side note - the `reunite` procedure as written is really an `union` operation between two lists, and it can be implemented in a simpler way as follows:

```
(define (reunite L1 L2)
  (foldr (lambda (e init)
           (if (member e init)
               init
               (cons e init)))
         L2
         L1))
```